# Components in my JPanel not centered

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, border-layout

I have a problem with the BorderLayout... In the headerPanel, all components should be centered but it appears that they are all shifted above.

And could you explain me why without the "this.add(new JPanel())" all the layout is completly destructed ?

Screenshot:

[image: http://puu.sh/gBoP4/60eaebe3bb.png]

```
 public class HomePanel extends IDPanel {

 private static final String DATE = "Par date";
 private static final String ENTREPRISE = "Par entreprise";
 private static final String PDC = "Par PDC";
 private static final String ACCESS = "Accès";
 private static final String NAME = "Nom";
 private static final String ADRESSE = "Adresse";
 private static final String PART_STATE = "Etat de la participation";


 private BasicArrowButton rowRight;
 private BasicArrowButton rowLeft;
 private JButton newJourneyButton;
 private JButton researchOkButton;
 private JButton adminButton;
 private JButton deconnexionButton;
 private JComboBox<String> researchChoice;
 private JTextField research;
 private JLabel errorMsg;
 private JLabel userHello;
 private JLabel entrepriseJourney;
 private JLabel entrepriseAccess;
 private JLabel entrepriseName;
 private JLabel entrepriseAdresse;
 private JLabel entreprisePart;

 private JPanel headerJPanel;
 private JPanel headerWest;
 private JPanel headerCenter;
 private JPanel headerEast;


    public HomePanel(boolean isAdmin) {
super();
this.setId(IHMConstantes.ID_HOME_PANEL);
String[] test = {DATE, ENTREPRISE, PDC};
if (isAdmin) {
  adminButton = new JButton("ADMIN");
}

rowRight = new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.RIGHT);
rowLeft = new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.LEFT);
newJourneyButton = new JButton("Nouvelle journée");
researchOkButton = new JButton("OK");
deconnexionButton = new JButton("Déconnexion");
researchChoice = new JComboBox<>(test);
research = new JTextField("Rechercher...");
errorMsg = new JLabel("");
userHello = new JLabel("Bonjour Utilisateur.Prenom");
entrepriseJourney = new JLabel("Entre.journée");
entrepriseAccess = new JLabel(ACCESS);
entrepriseName = new JLabel(NAME);
entrepriseAdresse = new JLabel(ADRESSE);
entreprisePart = new JLabel(PART_STATE);


headerJPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
headerWest = new JPanel();
headerCenter = new JPanel();
headerEast = new JPanel();
headerWest.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
headerCenter.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
headerEast.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));

if (isAdmin) {
  headerJPanel.setBounds(45, 75, 655, 50);
  adminButton.setBounds(700, 75, 90, 50);
} else {
  headerJPanel.setBounds(80, 75, 680, 50);
}
deconnexionButton.setBounds(650, 20, 150, 25);
userHello.setBounds(335, 190, 200, 20);
newJourneyButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 25));
headerWest.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 0));
headerEast.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(290, 0));

if (isAdmin) {
  this.add(adminButton);
}
this.add(deconnexionButton);
this.add(userHello);
this.add(headerJPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
this.add(new JPanel());
headerJPanel.add(headerWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
headerJPanel.add(headerCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
headerJPanel.add(headerEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
headerWest.add(newJourneyButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
headerCenter.add(rowLeft);
headerCenter.add(entrepriseJourney);
headerCenter.add(rowRight);
headerEast.add(researchChoice);
headerEast.add(research);
headerEast.add(researchOkButton);

// entrepriseJourney.add(entrepriseAccess);
// entrepriseJourney.add(entrepriseName);
// entrepriseJourney.add(entrepriseAdresse);
// entrepriseJourney.add(entreprisePart);

if (isAdmin) {
  adminButton.addActionListener(e -> {

  });
}

deconnexionButton.addActionListener(e -> {

});

newJourneyButton.addActionListener(e -> {

});

researchOkButton.addActionListener(e -> {

});

researchOkButton.addActionListener(e -> {

});

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using layouts incorrectly:

- You're calling `setBounds(...)` on components something that only works with `null` layouts, which is a layout that you should not be using.
- You're placing everything inside of a JPanel that uses a default FlowLayout
- And I'm guessing that you're setting the sizes of your top level window  rather than calling `pack()` on this window.

Instead you will want to:

- Be careful with use of FlowLayout, especially with inadvertent use as it is one of the "dumbest" layout managers. Don't get me wrong -- it has its uses, but I usually avoid using it as the layout of my "master" JPanel, the one that holds most of my GUI's components as you're doing.
- Avoid calling `setSize(...)` or `setPreferredSize(...)`
- Avoid calling `setBounds(...)` on **anything**
- Avoid temptation to use `null` layout.
- Call `pack()` on your GUI *after* adding all components and before calling `setVisible(true)`
- If still stuck, show a picture of your desired GUI layout
- And post code that doesn't have a lot of junk not related to your problem. For instance, the code you post should compile, should run, and shouldn't extend IDPanel or have dependencies on anything that we don't have access to.